# Angularjs ng-repeat for Dynamicform input and fieldset

Tags: angularjs

Please click on the demo below

www.jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/1370

> My problem is: "Add input" is working fine. But whenever i invoke "Add
>   Fields", the subsequent field will be sync with the first one. I want
>   the subsequent to be filled with only one input. I am currently using 2 array choices and choices2.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because you are bingding them with the same `$scope.choices`. I would recommend you to assign the `$scope.choices` into `$scope.choices2` so that they will become specific fields.

```
$scope.choices2 = [
  {
    id: 'choice1',
    choices: [{id: 'choice1'}]
  }
];
```

and at inner `ng-repeat`, bind the fields with `$scope.choices2.choices`

```
<div  data-ng-repeat="choice in choice.choices ">
```

refer this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/1371/).

fixed [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/1373/).

Comment: There's a bug. For new fieldset, whenever I add a input. The new fieldset and the old will get a input. Would like to have a delete and new input button for each fieldset independently

Comment: @Tosm it's  not bug at all, you just bind them with the same object `choices.name`

Comment: @Tosm  for me, I would move `Add Input` button into `ng-repeat` to let it just add specific input for each section, see the fixed example, hope it'll help. :-)

Comment: @Tosm let me know if you further problems :-)